# Pulling files from FTP server is not creating directory based on files date

Tags: powershell

I have a script that is able to connect via FTP, able to pull files,  but not creating a directory based on files date modified/ 
Goal is to put all these files into a directory, since this script will be running daily.
I tried pass the following params:

```
param(
 [string]$date =[datetime]((Get-Date).AddDays(-4)).ToString(“MM\dd\yyyy"),
 [string]$FilesToExcludeArray = @(""),
 [string]$FilesToIncludeArray = @("*.*"),
 [string]$remotepath ="/inbox/"
 [string]$localpath="c:\test\APRIL\$date\"
 )
```

I will not post the full script
but this is where $date is called after

```
   # Select the most recent files

  $latest = $directory.Files |
  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $date -and -Not $_.IsDirectory -and $_.Name -notlike 
  $FilesToExcludeArray -and $_.Name -like $FilesToIncludeArray}| Select-Object  
  $download = $False
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: Please show us how you defined `$directory`.

Answer (score 0):

You should make Lastwritetime in correct format:

```
$latest = $directory.Files | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM\dd\yyyy") -ge $date -and -Not $_.IsDirectory -and $_.Name -notlike $FilesToExcludeArray -and $_.Name -like $FilesToIncludeArray}
$download = $False
```

Comment: It ended up downloading multiple files from different days and not creating a folder

Comment: Nowhere is your code are you telling it to create a directory for the downloads.

Comment: No, you should instead remove the `ToString` formatting stuff on the date and compare the two **DateTime** objects, not their string representation.

Comment: @postanote it is a follow-up to create directory based on the date properly.

Comment: @Theo .NET compare-OPs turn the second operand type to the type of first one, so isn't the DateTime being converted to a string and being compared?

Comment: Even then, because the format used is not `yyyyMMdd`, the comparison would fail. Better always compare DateTime objects to DateTime objects. Do formatting when needed afterwards. Also, the format used has (back)slashes in it, so unsuitable for a filename.